# Are there any countries that require political parties to be democratically organised (and accept members)?

Tags: election, democracy, parliament

In many countries, members of parliament are elected on the title of political parties.  For example, in The Netherlands, [81 parties](https://www.kiesraad.nl/verkiezingen/inhoud/tweede-kamer/partijnamen-en-logos/register) have registered for the [Dutch General Election, 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_general_election,_2017).  In most of those parties, the political programme and electoral lists are — at least in theory — democratically decided by the members.  One of those parties (Party for Freedom, currently polling as the largest party at 21% of the vote), [only has a single member](http://www.parlement.com/id/vhnnmt7m4rqi/partij_voor_de_vrijheid_pvv) (Geert Wilders). The party itself is effectively a dictatorship (but literally speaking, also a perfect democracy).

I have read a proposal (not supported by Mr. Wilders) to require parties that wish to participate in the elections to be democratically organised and member-based, arguing that it would make democracy less vulnerable (the wannabe-dictator could then be ousted by his own party members even if he has a majority in parliament).  Regardless of whether or not such a requirement would actually help, my question is:

Are there any parliamentary systems where such a requirement for political parties exists, to accept members and be democratically organised?

Comment: Aren't the Netherlands a Parlamentary Monarchy? I mean, even if the party has only one member, if it succeeds it will have X MPs, and if they do not agree with Mr. Wilders policies they can vote against his measures and ever expel him from the PM position, isn't that right?

Comment: Oh, and Spain requires internal democratic structures but does not specify a clear minimum, it seems that it can be as low as three (which still allows for a dictatorship since it will be me, Mom & Pop).

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes.  The MPs are formally independent even if they are elected on his title, so they would be in a position to oust him from power.  I believe the PVV officially has two members: Mr. Wilders and the Foundation for Mr. Wilders, through which it meets the legal minimum, but only one member is human.

Comment: No, party with a single member is a perfect democracy as well as a perfect dictatorship. An in-party voting system would change nothing for a party with only 1 member. My wild guess is that Dutch law does require that General Assembly be an ultimate source of power in a party, it's just that GA is one person here.

Comment: "the wannabe-dictator could then be overruled by his own party even if he has a majority in parliament" Could overrule him on what? Party members cannot vote on legislation or motions of no confidence.

Comment: @suriv They could remove him from the position of party leader.  Replaced *overruled* by *ousted* as this is more accurate.

Comment: @Agent_L Indeed, and your guess may be right.  See also [Philipps answer](http://politics.stackexchange.com/a/14631/130), which indicates that in Germany, a party with one member that does not accept any other members would be unconstitutional.

Comment: @Agent_L: No, Dutch Law restricts parties to be a particular type of legal entity ("Vereniging") which by law must have 2 members. The Wilders loophole is that they don't need to be 2 _human_ members.

Comment: @MSalters Additionally, membership doesn't need to be open. So membership can be limited to the two founding members (which are, IIRC, Wilders himself and a foundation).

Comment: I find the requirement to be a control of political speeches - how people organize for political purposes is a form of political speeches. Why should we prohibited non-democratic forms of political organization when we insist that government shouldn't be in thee business of controlling how people voice their views?

Comment: @dannyf Whether or not such a requirement is desirable is subjective and beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @gerrit: but we can certainly say that a country that would have such requirements would be very anti-democratic.

Comment: @Joël No, we can't.  That is a subjective judgement, not a certainty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, in neighboring Germany for example. The German Grundgesetz (constitution) Article 21, Section 1, says ([original German](https://dejure.org/gesetze/GG/21.html) | [official English translation](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gg/englisch_gg.html#p0118)):

> (1) Political parties shall participate in the formation of the political will of the people. They may be freely established. Their internal organisation must conform to democratic principles. [...]

The [Political Parties Act (PartG)](http://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Gesetzestexte/Parteiengesetz_PartG_engl_042009.pdf;jsessionid=8935432DFCF349B5410D39C235488A9F.2_cid287?__blob=publicationFile) implements this article with some more specific restrictions on how parties need to be organized internally.

A one-person-party would not be legal according to this law. Section 2 (10) says that parties must *"offer a sufficient guarantee of their sincerity [...] especially as regards the size and strength of their organization, **their membership numbers** and their visibility in public"*. It doesn't give a specific minimum size, but I doubt anyone would disagree that "one" is insufficient. Further, section 10 (1) says *"No general refusal to admit new members, even if of limited duration, shall be permissible."*. That means parties must be open to accepting new members. Even though they don't need to accept everyone. The same section also reads *"the party shall freely decide on the admission of members. No reasons need to be given for rejecting
an application for membership"*. So if a party claims to be open to new members but rejects everyone for undisclosed reasons, it's up to the prosecution to prove that they refuse everyone and are not just very picky.

Answer (score 2):

I think requirements of internal democracy are quite general.

[Spanish constitution](https://www.boe.es/legislacion/documentos/ConstitucionCASTELLANO.pdf) as another example:

> Article 6. Los partidos políticos (...) Su estructura interna y
>   funcionamiento deberán ser democráticos.

My translation:

> Their [of political parties] internal structure and function must be democratic.

The [law on political parties](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2002-12756) is more specific (article 3 j), when stating what should be in party bylaws:

> j) El procedimiento para la elección de los órganos directivos, bien
>   directamente o por representación, que en todo caso deberá garantizar
>   la participación de todos los afiliados mediante sufragio libre y
>   secreto, y los procedimientos de control democrático de los dirigentes
>   electos.

My translation:

> The process to elect directive positions, directly or by representations, that in any case must allow participation of all members through free and secret suffrage, and the democratic control of elect directive members.

Articles 6, 7 and 8 expand on that.

---

**Update:**

The sources pointed by CptEric ask for a minimum of 3 members as any other association. However, I'm not sure about if a party could be registered with less members, mainly because the law of political parties doesn't reference the laws about associations, which aren't uniform in the whole country. Probably, if a party were rejected registering because of lack of enough members, the issue could end in court.

Comment: Is there any requirement to be open to members?  See the comments about Wilders' party having two members, being democratic *de jure*.

Comment: There is a requirement against forced affiliation and for freedom to leave the party (article 1.2) but as far as I can see party bylaws can establish requisites for joining (article 3.2.g). I can't also find requirements about minimum number of members.

Comment: There is an electoral college organization that makes sure that the parties are democratic, and they choose how to interpret the constitution, hence, if a party is found to be a two-person tandem closed to anybody else, they could illegalize it. A party still has it's right to say "no" to a new member. Parties must work, althought, as associations, and that requires atleast  4 members, ( President, Vicepresident, treasurer,Secretary), who must be elected.

Comment: sources : https://sede.mir.gob.es/procedimientos/partidos_politicos/formularios/solicitudes_registro_partidos.html

Comment: more sources: http://195.235.66.22/web/guest/como-inscribir-un-partido